# How do I troubleshoot ipython-listener and/or gedit's ipython plugin?

Tags: python, ipython, gedit, gedit-plugin

I am running Gedit 3.8.3, Python 2.7.5+ and IPython 0.13.2 and the [Gedit Ipython Plugin](http://www.cogsci.nl/software/gedit-ipython-plugin).

I know there are better IDEs for Python out there but this used to "just work" and then I got a new machine and installed Ubuntu 13.10 and it doesn't work anymore. The plugin used to give me an error, `(gedit:23136): libpeas-WARNING **: Could not find loader 'python' for plugin 'ipython'` but I followed [some advice on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291454/problem-with-gedit-plugins-and-python3-on-13-04/302431#302431) and edited the Loader line in `/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/ipython.plugin` to `Loader=python3` and it now loads without error but also doens't *do* anything. Whether or not `iPython-listener` is running, the error I see in the console is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/ipython.py", line 98, in send_to_ipython
    self.socket.sendto(code, (self.listener_host, self.listener_port) )     
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: Try opening the file with that line of code in and changing `code` to `code.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: Bingo! If you make that an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I've opened an issue on the plugin as well: https://github.com/smathot/gedit-plugin-ipython/issues/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

The gedit IPython plugin appears to be written for Python 2 only, but it looks like it only takes a small change to adapt it to Python 3. Find the line on which the error occurred:

```
self.socket.sendto(code, (self.listener_host, self.listener_port) )
```

And change it to this:

```
self.socket.sendto(code.encode('utf-8'), (self.listener_host, self.listener_port) )
```

UTF-8 should be the right default on most modern Linux systems.